# CodeIgniter: Session ends on new session id generation

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0.0 and I have a problem where the session keeps getting destroyed when a new session ID is generated.  This is my session config.  So in this example the session always times out after 300 seconds.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I've debugged it and narrowed it down to line 625 of the `system/libraries/Session/Session.php`

```
public function sess_regenerate($destroy = FALSE)
{
    $_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate'] = time();
    session_regenerate_id($destroy); //If I uncomment this line it fixes the bug
}
```

I could just disable session regeneration but I know this is important for security reasons.  Has anyone else had this problem?

It's worth me pointing out that **I don't get this problem locally** so maybe it's something to do this my server set up?

Comment: There may be something wrong with how you handle authentication, can you show which authorization system or library is used in your setup?

Comment: Upgrade CI first. There are ~20 session-related bug fixes *since* 3.0.0; the latest version is 3.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on PHP7 and has been solved. Upgrade your CI to 3.1.2 or above.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_312.html.